# TicTacToe Tkinter GUI keeps crashing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, crash, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make a simply TicTacToe game using Tkinter but I can't really test it because the application keeps crashing. I can't get further than the second round. Can anyone tell me why it keeps crashing? It seems to have gotten a little better after implementing the `after()` method, but it still doesn't run properly.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randrange


# click function
def choose(event):
    global game_over
    if not game_over:
        if event.widget["state"] == "normal":
            event.widget.configure(text="O", disabledforeground="#0000ff", state="disabled")
            # check for winner
            window.after(1000, check)
            # let computer make its move
            if not game_over:
                window.after(1000, machine_move)
                # check again
                window.after(1000, check)
        elif event.widget["state"] == "disabled":
            messagebox.showerror("Field taken", "Please choose a different field")


# define machine move
def machine_move():
    global taken
    pick = randrange(1, 9)
    taken = True
    while taken:
        if button_dict[pick-1].cget("state") == "normal":
            button_dict[pick-1].configure(text="X", disabledforeground="#ff0000", state="disabled")
            taken = False


# check for winner function
def check():
    global game_over
    global inputs
    inputs = []
    for key in button_dict.keys():
        inputs.append(button_dict[key].cget("text"))
    # line win
    if inputs[0] == "X" and inputs[1] == "X" and inputs[2] == "X" \
    or inputs[3] == "X" and inputs[4] == "X" and inputs[5] == "X" \
    or inputs[6] == "X" and inputs[7] == "X" and inputs[8] == "X":
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Line win by machine")
        game_over = True
    elif inputs[0] == "O" and inputs[1] == "O" and inputs[2] == "O" \
    or inputs[3] == "O" and inputs[4] == "O" and inputs[5] == "O" \
    or inputs[6] == "O" and inputs[7] == "O" and inputs[8] == "O":
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Line win by you")
        game_over = True
    # row win
    elif inputs[0] == "X" and inputs[3] == "X" and inputs[6] == "X" \
    or inputs[1] == "X" and inputs[4] == "X" and inputs[7] == "X" \
    or inputs[2] == "X" and inputs[5] == "X" and inputs[8] == "X":
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Row win by machine")
        game_over = True
    elif inputs[0] == "O" and inputs[3] == "O" and inputs[6] == "O" \
    or inputs[1] == "O" and inputs[4] == "O" and inputs[7] == "O" \
    or inputs[2] == "O" and inputs[5] == "O" and inputs[8] == "O":
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Row win by you")
        game_over = True
    # check for diagonal win
    elif inputs[0] == "X" and inputs[4] == "X" and inputs[8] == "X" \
    or inputs[2] == "X" and inputs[4] == "X" and inputs[6] == "X":
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Diagonal win by machine")
        game_over = True
    elif inputs[0] == "O" and inputs[4] == "O" and inputs[8] == "O" \
    or inputs[2] == "O" and inputs[4] == "O" and inputs[6] == "O":
        messagebox.showinfo("Game over", "Diagonal win by machine")
        game_over = True


# create window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("TicTacToe")
window.geometry("450x480")


# create buttons

button_dict = {}
for i in range(9):
    new_button = tk.Button(window, text=" ", width=3, font=30)
    new_button.grid(column=i // 3, row=i % 3, ipadx=50, ipady=50)
    new_button.bind("<Button-1>", choose)
    button_dict[i] = new_button


# start game
game_over = False
button_dict[4].configure(text="X", disabledforeground="#ff0000", state="disabled")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the body of the while-loop in your `machine_move` function, the variable `pick` never changes from its initial state. So, if the randomly picked button happens to be disabled, you never break out of the loop, and the program hangs.

Answer (score 0):

As also stated by @Paul M in the comments, if the `pick` variable in the `machine_move` function happens to be of the button that is already disabled, its value will remain unchanged and the while loop keeps running indefinitely causing your program to hang. To get over this, you can try the following (this is one of the many solutions possible to tackle this)

```py
def machine_move():
    available_buttons=[button_dict[i] for i in range(len(button_dict)) if button_dict[i].cget("state") == "normal"]
    pick = choice(available_buttons)
    pick.configure(text="X", disabledforeground="#ff0000", state="disabled")
```

So, basically the list `available_buttons` contains the buttons that have not been disabled yet, the variable `pick` is a random choice (using `random.choice()`) from that list and then is being configured accordingly.

**UPDATE**

I have also noticed that you are using the `after` method to call for `check()`, this may lead to a significant delay in deciding the winner and sometimes multiple winners if another move is made before the check is called, to overcome this you could try this instead (again, this is one of the many solutions possible to tackle this)

```py
def choose(event):
    global game_over
    if not game_over:
        if event.widget["state"] == "normal":
            event.widget.configure(text="O", disabledforeground="#0000ff", state="disabled")
            # check for winner
            check()
            # let computer make its move
            if not game_over:
                window.after(1000, machine_move)
        elif event.widget["state"] == "disabled":
            messagebox.showerror("Field taken", "Please choose a different field")


# define machine move
def machine_move():
    available_buttons=[button_dict[i] for i in range(len(button_dict)) if button_dict[i].cget("state") == "normal"]
    pick = choice(available_buttons)
    pick.configure(text="X", disabledforeground="#ff0000", state="disabled")
    check()
```

Call `check()` right after the player or the machine makes the move.